# "today" is not able to localize in timeline

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, timeline, russian-stackoverflow

For any recent question with daily score section "today" is not able to localize, i.e. there are no suitable strings in transifex.

Link itself:

> [image: today]

Tooltip, when toggle format is pressed:

> [image: хинт]

P.S. Screenshots are from related [question on meta.ruSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4329/176217).

Answer (score 2):

Sure enough, we were missing a localization call on that string. I pushed the fix. It should propagate to Transifex... eventually. Although I'd be surprised if "today" wasn't translated already somewhere else, so if there's an existing translation, it should just get picked up with the next production build.

Comment: I can't find now "today" in question's timeline at all (even on English part of SE). What conditions must be met to see it? I know only about having votes.

Comment: [Seems completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3zsR.png). Thanx.