# User RSS feed is terribly localized

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed, localization, russian-stackoverflow

Many strings which appeared in a user RSS feed (located in the activity tab in the profile page) don't have localization calls (as far as I can see). More information is located in [a related post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4512/176217) on ruSO.meta.

If the Stack Overflow team needs some clarification/translation - let me know.

Comment: Why report it twice? You already reported it on the other meta.

Comment: @PatrickHofman according to my [previous post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290273/339911) here (on meta.SE), bugs posted on ruSO.meta site is less noticeable. They get lost over time.

Comment: Then don't post them there. What if a moderator there goes to all the trouble to report it to the developers and it ends up already fixed...

Comment: @PatrickHofman bug that already fixed is the best bug I think.

Comment: @PatrickHofman now I prefer to post bugs only on meta.SE. Old related post was created before I realized that most of bugs which can't be fixed without english spoken developers should be posted **only** here. Also, as far as I know policy about bug fixing in SO team is changed recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some translations were missing, and the user name was never appearing in the "Comment by" section due to a bug. Fixed.